# Completely removing cache

Tags: 8, caching

I've set `$settings['cache']['bins']['render'] = 'cache.backend.null;` and `$settings['cache']['bins']['dynamic_page_cache'] = 'cache.backend.null;` in local.settings.php, but I’m having a hard time dumping variables out to a page from a hook that runs once early on (`hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()`). If I do a simple var_dump (or dpm, etc.)  from here, variables will show up when running `drush cr` in the console, but not when hitting a new page in the browser afterwards. Does anyone know how I can set up debugging so I'm able to look at these variables in the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did only uses the null backend render cache bins.

Field definitions are cached in the discovery bin, you either have to set that to null as well, but that will make your site very slow. You can also simply truncate `cache_discovery` manually in the database and then do another request in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the great answer from Berdir for the specific problem this is for the more general question in the title:

You never have a completely cleared cache and it would nearly be impossible to remove all caching activities from drupal, because there are too many.

`drush cr` does not only clear caching tables, but also rebuilds all essential data drupal needs to organize itself like database schemas and routing. The code involving this is then not rerun on a request.

To get the debug output in the browser a simple solution would be to clear and rebuild the cache in the browser instead of drush.

But I found debugging these things with drush quite effective by reading the debugging messages in the console, make a quick change in code and run drush again.